# Packages are not installing

Tags: octave

```
pkg install -forge io
```

produces:

```
"error: get_forge_pkg: could not read URL, please verify internet connection"
```

but I am connected to the internet.

Comment: Versions and OS?

Comment: Octave 4.0.0 Windows 10

Comment: can you try `pkg install -forge io -verbose` and see if it gives you any further useful info?

Comment: Chris, please install Octave 5.1, it includes the io package, no need to install it with -forge isntall

Comment: Octave 4.4  also included a version on the io package, so you shouldn't need to install it unless you wanted to upgrade.